# How to make two specific lengths of regression lines in a single plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, regression, scatter-plot

I did linear regression in minitab

I want to produce a nice plot in R but I cannot figure out how to limit the length of the lines. I was be able to produce something like 
this [image]
but I want to limit the length of the lines and want to make one just like the minitab output. 
Thanks for your time and help !

Here is the code:

```
plot(y=c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2),  x=c(-102,-100,-98,-96,-94,-92), type="n", xlab = 'Longitude', ylab = 'Factor4Score')
g <- points(f1[1:38] ~ LON[1:38], col = "red", pch=21)
g.lm <-lm(f4[1:38] ~ LON[1:38])
abline(g.lm, col = "red")
plot(y=c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2), x=c(-102,-100,-98,-96,-94,-92), type="n", xlab = 'Longitude', ylab = 'Factor3Score')
s <-points(f4[39:102] ~ LON[39:102], col="green",pch=23 )
s.lm <-lm(f4[39:102] ~ LON[39:102])
abline(s.lm, col = "green")
```

Comment: Show your code. And use `segments` instead of whatever you are using to plot the lines.

Comment: Here is the code:
 plot(y=c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2),  x=c(-102,-100,-98,-96,-94,-92), type="n", xlab = 'Longitude', ylab = 'Factor4Score')
g <- points(f1[1:38] ~ LON[1:38], col = "red", pch=21)
 g.lm <-lm(f4[1:38] ~ LON[1:38])
abline(g.lm, col = "red")
s <-points(f4[39:102] ~ LON[39:102], col="green",pch=23 ) 
s.lm <-lm(f4[39:102] ~ LON[39:102])
abline(s.lm, col = "green")

Comment: Please edit the code into the original post so that it is easier to read. Also, as @Gregor mentioned, use `segments` instead of `abline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
abline(g.lm, col = "red")
abline(s.lm, col = "green")
```

you can use the built in lines() function to create your regression lines.

In your example, I would use

```
lines(x = -102:-95, y = coefficients(g.lm)[1] + coefficients(g.lm)[2]* (-102:-95), col = 'red')
lines(x = -95:-92, y = coefficients(s.lm)[1] + coefficients(s.lm)[2]* (-95:-92), col = 'green')
```